# Display AWS BOTO upload status in html

Tags: django, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im using Django and Angular js. I upload the photos on s3 using BOTO. How can I get the upload status using django and display it using angular js?

I have this functions:

```
def percent_cb(complete, total):
    print '%d bytes transferred out of %d' % (complete, total)


def upload_to_s3(project_file):
    sourceDir = photos_folder + project_file +'/'
    destDir = '/photos/'+ project_file +'/'
    MAX_SIZE = 20 * 1000 * 1000
    PART_SIZE = 6 * 1000 * 1000

    conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)

    k = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket)
    k.key = destpat
    k.set_contents_from_filename(sourcepath, cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10)
```

Here's the log when I upload a sample photo:

```
0 bytes transferred out of 508450
57344 bytes transferred out of 508450
114688 bytes transferred out of 508450
172032 bytes transferred out of 508450
229376 bytes transferred out of 508450
286720 bytes transferred out of 508450
344064 bytes transferred out of 508450
401408 bytes transferred out of 508450
458752 bytes transferred out of 508450
508450 bytes transferred out of 508450
```

I want to get output of the percent_cb everytime it prints and pass it to angular for the html display..

Is their any way to do this?

- thanks